# duplicate data and dates

Tags: r, date

I am bit of a newbie to R I have two questions. I have a dataframe, say `FruitsNew`

```
   Fruit 
1 Apples
2 Oranges
3 Bananas
```

Q1) I want to  duplicate the data and add monthly dates starting from 31-May-2000 to the above, for example

```
   Fruit  date
1 Apples  2000-05-31  
2 Oranges 2000-05-31
3 Bananas 2000-05-31
4 Apples  2000-06-30
5 Oranges 2000-06-30
6 Bananas 2000-06-30
```

and so on...

Q2) After I obtain the above, I merge it with a Sales dataset which is only available yearly at end of May so it looks like this

```
  Fruit   date          sales
1 Apples  2000-05-31    1000
2 Oranges 2000-05-31     
3 Bananas 2000-05-31    500    
4 Apples  2000-06-30
5 Oranges 2000-06-30
6 Bananas 2000-06-30
...
7 Apples  2001-05-31    2000   
8 Oranges 2001-05-31    200
9 Bananas 2001-05-31    600
```

The oranges don't have sales, but I would like to fill it with a 0 for all the monthly dates between 05/31/2000 and the next available sales data which occurs in 05/31/2001
The other fruits should have the same sales number between 05/31/2000 and 05/31/2001 and so on.

The above is just an example but the idea is if missing to fill the previously available sales number for the date, if previously available date is empty then fill 0

Something like this

```
  Fruit   date           sales
1 Apples  2000-05-31     1000    
2 Oranges 2000-05-31     0
3 Bananas 2000-05-31     500    
4 Apples  2000-06-30     1000
5 Oranges 2000-06-30     0
6 Bananas 2000-06-30     500
7 Apples  2001-05-31     2000   
8 Oranges 2001-05-31     200
9 Bananas 2001-05-31     600
```

Comment: What does the sales data frame look like?

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your first dataframe will be named `core` and your second dataframe named `merg.yr`:

```
merg.yr <- merge(core, year.sale, by.x=1:2, by.y=1:2, all.x=TRUE)
merg.yr[is.na(merg.yr)] <- 0
```

To build the `core` df I came up with a method that created the dates at the first of the months, then subtracted 1 from each to get the last date in the prior month. I then repeated each one three times and let the `data.frame function fill in the fruits:

```
core <- data.frame(fruit =c('Apples','Oranges','Bananas'), 
                  date=rep( as.Date(seq(ISOdate(2000, 6,1), 
                                        ISOdate(2001,6,1), by='month')) -1,
                            each=3)
                  )
```